# Help building a small solar charging kit

Tags: solar-cell, setup

I'm trying to build a cheap light system for an NGO in Kenya, that will allow a family to have light using solar panels. If you're familiar with the new [m-kopa](http://www.m-kopa.com/) service offered by Safaricom the setup I'm trying to achieve is very similar, except that it would use a car battery as the storage unit.

What I have so far for the testing is a 5W/12V solar panel that would charge the battery and afterwards use that power to **supply electricity for a few led lightbulbs, phone charging, a so forth**.

I thought of car batteries because they're readily available in the area and I think (I have no electronic or electrical knowledge) that with the use of an inverter or convertor for expanding the setup in the future to power hungrier devices.

Please excuse me if I'm saying things wrong, I'm just the project creator and would like to understand if it's viable and what the cost of this setup would be, I'm not asking about the prices here, just what the setup would look like.

Connecting the solar panel to the battery would charge it, that's something I've seen on DIY videos and so forth, but I'm worried about overcharging and the dangers it carries.

Thanks in advance to any that may answer

Comment: This is a very broad question. We can't write a whole book on setting up a solar charged off-grid system, which of course has been done many times. 5W isn't very much. You're not going to overcharge a car battery with that, even if run indefinitely. My first knee jerk reaction is that your panel is grossly undersized.  However, what *specifically* is your question?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2W poly-silicon based panels that are designed as "battery maintainers" for storage of cars.  They work well even in winter at latitudes of 40+ and a rainy environment behind a windshield (direct experience).  So very low insolation and lots of light reduction going on.  This basically offsets leakage and keeps the battery from going flat which can be bad for longevity.

Most panels are rated for an insolation that corresponds to mid-latitude US and summertime conditions this is known as STC (Standard Test Conditions) so that little 2W panel mentioned above may have been producing ~ only 1W peak at best.  Keep in mond that was **only** ensuring that the battery is charged for the next spring.

In equatorial Kenya, especially at higher elevations the insolation will be 3 - 4X of the scenario above. So closer to 2.5 W for much longer during the day.  The total Energy (W*Hr) in Kenya vs. winter temperate example will be much much higher simply because the light will be available for longer in the day.  Insolation maps for the all areas are available.

Is your 5W sufficient?  well more than sufficient to keep the battery charged.  If it's enough for all the units (like lights etc.) that need supplying is another thing because that depends upon demand.  I would recommend that you look at that side of the equation first to allow you to supply parameters for the design.

Since cost is so extremely constrained, here is one approach to consider.
The smaller the panel the better.  With a small panel your charging becomes almost an non-issue and is safe.  But then the issue shifts to how do I prevent the battery from being overdrawn so that the small panel has a chance to recharge it the next day.  the design shifts to having a simple monitoring circuit that allows only so much power to be drawn and then protects the battery (with an over-ride for emergency).

Of course there are other ways of doing this with different balances of panels, batteries and circuit sophistication and cost.  The social elements are probably the main area where your project is going to fail or win.

Here are some numbers:

- Nokia feature phone uses a BL-5CB battery 800mAh @ 3.7 V -> 3 W*h -> call it 4W*h with inefficiencies.
- White LED lamp draws 10W @ ~ 1000 Lumens (60w incandescent = ~1000 Lumens) at 4 hours/night = 40 Wh -> 50 Wh with inefficiencies.

  - note this is totally un-realistic, as this LED would be very very expensive.
  - a reading light need not be ~ 1000 lumens either.
  - so lets cut this in 1/2 -> 25 Wh needed
- worst case scenarion 25 Wh + 5 Wh = 30 Wh might well be doable with a 5W panel and 6 hours a day of sunlight.